# NPM install from Github, ambiguous argument

Tags: node.js, git

I am trying to install from a private github repo. The first 3 private repositories install just fine. The final one errors out error shown below. I have permission to access, pull from, and push to the repo. I have tried removing the version number but I get the same error with "ambiguous argument 'master'." The other 3 repositories have the same format for the install command.

```
PS C:\Users\shutez\Documents\Simple Emotion\Code\sedemo.tk> npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:SimpleEmotion/node-call
-analytics.git#0.4.1
npm ERR! Failed resolving git HEAD (git@github.com:SimpleEmotion/node-call-analytics.git) fatal: ambiguous argument '0.4
.1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
npm ERR! Failed resolving git HEAD (git@github.com:SimpleEmotion/node-call-analytics.git) Use '--' to separate paths fro
m revisions, like this:
npm ERR! Failed resolving git HEAD (git@github.com:SimpleEmotion/node-call-analytics.git) 'git <command> [<revision>...]
 -- [<file>...]'
npm ERR! Failed resolving git HEAD (git@github.com:SimpleEmotion/node-call-analytics.git)
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: ambiguous argument '0.4.1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
npm ERR! Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
npm ERR! 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:647:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
 "install" "git+ssh://git@github.com:SimpleEmotion/node-call-analytics.git#0.4.1"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\shutez\Documents\Simple Emotion\Code\sedemo.tk
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shutez\Documents\Simple Emotion\Code\sedemo.tk\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: That particular repository doesn't exist (anymore): https://github.com/SimpleEmotion/node-call-analytics

Comment: @robertklep If it's a private repo then you wouldn't be able to see it :P. [This repo](https://github.com/chevex/amigo) of mine definitely exists, but to you I'm sure it's a 404 ;)

Comment: @AlexFord duh, I missed that it's a private repo, sorry :(

Comment: @ZacharyShute did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fix is simple.

> $ npm update -g npm

Your npm is out of date. Your log says you're using 1.4.9 and the latest version is 2.11.0.

Cheers!

Comment: I just had this issue 6 years later, and updating from npm 7.10 to 7.24 fixed it for me. Weird!

Answer (score 3):

### Repo Does Not Exist

I ran into this because I was trying to do an `npm install` on a project I hadn't touched in a while and the `package.json` file was referencing a repository that had been deleted.

In my specific case, it was the following line in my `package.json` file that was causing the problem:

```
"react-native-app-intro": "joshuapinter/react-native-app-intro#patch-1",
```

You can see that I was trying to pull the `patch-1` branch of the repository.

Well, this branch was actually one that I created to serve as a Pull Request to the original author and after the original author merged in the Pull Request, I instinctively removed the `patch-1` branch as it's no longer needed. But I did not update my `package.json` file to reference the original author's repository with my merged-in changes.

Anyway, pretty cryptic error message that npm spits out given how simple and common this must be, but hopefully this helps others save some time.